# Syntar erro unexpected '?' working locally

Tags: php

i have this code in the top of my index.php. And it works perfect when i run it locally with mamp. But when i go live with the page and upload it to the hosting service and launch the website i get this error in the log. And the site does not load.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in
>   /home/*****/*****.*****.**/index.php on line 3

```
<?php
session_start();
$AccountsucessRegister = $_SESSION['Accountsucess'] ?? '';
$AccountfailRegister  = $_SESSION['Accountfail'] ?? '';
unset($_SESSION['Accountsucess']);
unset($_SESSION['Accountfail']);
?>
 <?php if ($AccountsucessRegister !== ''): ?>
 <?php echo "<script>alert('$AccountsucessRegister');</script>" ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php if ($AccountfailRegister !== ''): ?>
 <?php echo "<script>alert('$AccountfailRegister');</script>" ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Look at the version of PHP using `phpinfo();` there's likely to be a difference in  version between your MAMP and your provider's

Comment: The null coalescing operator `??` only became available in PHP in version 7, so your hosting provider likely has an earlier version installed.

Comment: php7 locally and php5 on the hosting service? If that's the case you need to replace the null coalescing operator with the equivalent ternary operator. You can find an example in the  [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

Comment: Thank you, i did not know that the ?? became available in PHP version 7. I changed from php 5 to 7 and now it works great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have on local php7+ version and at your provider not.

Among provider have .ini file option to change the php version on shared hosting but if not the error comes from

```
$AccountsucessRegister = $_SESSION['Accountsucess'] ?? '';
```

must be

```
$AccountsucessRegister = isset($_SESSION['Accountsucess']) ? $_SESSION['Accountsucess'] : '';
```